# How can I make a Bootstrap container's row background go 100% window width?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, reactstrap

I have a container that works well for all sizes so far. It's fixed at its preset Bootstrap width, and it's centered.

I want to make the background color of a row stretch full width of the window, rather than the container.

Currently I have this basic structure:

```
<Container>

  <Row>
    <Col>

      data

    </Col>
  </Row>

  <Row style={{backgroundColor: 'grey'}}> //This should be 100% window width
    <Col>

      data

    </Col>
  </Row>

  <Row>
    <Col>

      data

    </Col>
  </Row>

</Container>
```

(by the way, using Components rather than `<div class="">` as it's Reactstrap)

Comment: Put the row outside the container and have 2 contains for the other rows. Everything doesn't have to be in the same container or inside a container unless you want to constrain the width.

Comment: You're king! Thanks Wizard!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the row inside the container, you can add calculated negative margin to the row with css like the following:

```
.row {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: calc((100vw - 100%) / -2) !important;
  padding-left: calc((100vw - 100%) / 2);
  margin-right: calc((100vw - 100%) / -2) !important;
  padding-right: calc((100vw - 100%) / 2);
}
```

See the following example:

```css
.example-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 150px;
}

.row{
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: calc((100vw - 100%) / -2) !important;
  padding-left: calc((100vw - 100%) / 2);
  margin-right: calc((100vw - 100%) / -2) !important;
  padding-right: calc((100vw - 100%) / 2);
}

.col {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="example-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Column 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```